# Regarding Multitasking in Android application

Tags: android

I want to launch more than one application at the same time.Like one application should run in the background when a new application is started, and I have to switch between those two application.

If anyone having the code to do this please help me.

Give some website links to know about the multitasking in android and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run something in the background, you have to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Services are not killed except in extreme memory situations. Read the [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) for more information.